# Is there a default 4-digit unlock code for an iPad (MD528LL/A)?

Tags: ipad

My mom updated her iPad MD528LL/A. After the update it wont let her in. It asks for a code - a 4 digit number. She didn’t set up a security code and cant get in it.

Is there a default security code? This thing is useless now. She updates it and now can’t use it.

Comment: did she write it down somewhere, used her bday ect... Actually it is not possible to have the security code without purposely setting it up. Bring it to Apple Store with proof of ownership.

Comment: Wow.. That is BS that apple does this crap. Really. My mother is 70. She did not set or want any pass code/word. the iPad said there was an update and that is what she did. Now to her it is broken. This was given to her from my sister. Now she has to PROVE she owns it? I am not mad at you i am mad at Apple. Not good.. Now i got to shop for an Android tablet. Really. I thought Apple;e had good support.

Comment: Calm down....Apple will not and can not set up the passcode for you. But since you mentioned, I bet your Sister set it up.

Comment: Well I know everyone says its impossible but the same thing just happened to my mother...right after the update. I came to this page hoping to find a solution. So strange...

Comment: And this is a new account so no settings to restore.

Answer (score 6):

No, there's no default passcode lock code. Any passcode lock will be set up in Settings and won't be caused by an update.

If you have a SIM card, then it will ask you for PIN code every time you restart the iPad. This is the only possibility coming to my mind. Does she have a SIM card? If no, then I really can not think of any other possibility.

Comment: um .. .no. My mother did not have a pas code set. At all. She did an update. NOW when she turns it on .. it wants a number code. .. So .. WHY is it asking for one IF Apple didn't set it to pop up after the update?

Comment: Again, no update from Apple will ever auto-generate a passcode.  Try speaking with your sister.  Stop being pointlessly upset with Apple and ask your sister.

Answer (score 2):

Apple will not and can not set the passcode for you. So NO there is no Default code.

Since you mentioned, I would guess your Sister set it up (so ask her), and your Mom newer turned it off :) so she newer needed it.

Comment: My sister (being Vegan) and my mon (who likes hamburgers) are, not really speaking to each other. In other words my sister is being an A$$. She refuses to help so im caught in the middle. I'm jsut trying to help her. My mom, today, is sayign to me that she will never use it. I said yes you will. Nope!

Comment: So, now my mom is stuck with a brick. nice of the "protection" the iPad has. This was a gift and this happens. She has had it for something like 2 years. . We have restarted the iPad numerous times. This is what puzzles me. THEN AFTER an update it asks for a security code.

Comment: Sorry, we can not solve your Family problems. Send your sister a link to this page and we can try to talk here in to been nice to her Mother. http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/181227/46541

Answer (score 0):

Your mother might accidentally setup the iPad by restoring backup from iCloud account. If the backup version was created when the passcode had been setup, then it will be restored to the passcode as well. Another possibility is that she backed up from your sister's account, in which case, you should ask your sister for the passcode. 
That's what I could think of for now. Gluck~

Comment: iOS backups don't restore the passcode.

Comment: She still cant log in to the iPad. There is a number pad expecting a - 4 digit number?